# How to register and identify single device on Android Things Console or How do we get a device onto a channel

Tags: android-things, android-things-console

I am new to IoT. I am going through the Android Things Console docs where it was written:

> You must flash the device with an image from the Android Things Console in order for the device to receive updates.

Here, I am not able to understand how devices get registered/enrolled on Android Things console and how we can identify a single device. How do you get a device onto a channel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an image in the console, the system image is linked to that product that you've created. This hidden identifier is used for future OTA updates.

It does not allow you to identify single devices. If you want that, you may want to use your own solution, which may involve a number of IoT solutions like Google Cloud IoT Core.

To get devices onto a channel, you can take a look at the [UpdateManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/update/UpdateManager).